# How to remove default sound when typing text in UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios

When we enter text to `UITextField` we get sound while typing text , how do I remove/disable that default sound (using code) and add other custom sound?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the default keyboard sound using any public API.

You can however, but that's a very ugly solution, intercept the delegate of UITextField and play a sound when a new character is entered. I don't recommend it, though.

Comment: No you can't change the default iOS sounds or stop it programatically.

Comment: Could you, in theory, using what you described, play an empty 1-second sound on click - wouldn't that sort of null out the key-clicks?

Comment: I don't think so. It would be superimposed with the keyboard click